# Parsing recursive hashes into data records in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash

I've struggled with this problem for a while, and I'm finally going to ask here for help.

Take a very straightforward hash that represents some event:

```
{
  :eventkey=>"someeventkey",
  :web_id=>"77d5f434-5a40-4582-88e8-9667b7774c7d",
  :apikey=>"eaf3b6e1-b020-41b6-b67f-98f1cc0a9590",
  :details=>  {
    :phone=>"1-936-774-6886",
    :email=>"dasia_schuster@wisokytrantow.com",
    :pageUrl=>"http://ortiz.info/joe"
    }
}
```

My goal is to create a 'master record' for the entire hash, with the fields in the record being all the keys that do not contain values that are also hashes.  When I run into a value that is a hash (in this case 'details'), I need to create a separate record for each k/v pair in that hash bearing the same record id as the parent master record.

I'm not getting the recursion right somehow.  Ideally I would get back a single primary record:

```
{
  :recordid=>"some-generated-record-id",
  :web_id=>"77d5f434-5a40-4582-88e8-9667b7774c7d",
  :apikey=>"eaf3b6e1-b020-41b6-b67f-98f1cc0a9590",
  :details=>nil
}
```

And a distinct entry for each key in the nested hash:

```
{ 
  :recordid=>"some-generated-detail-record-id",
  :parentid=>"the-parent-id-from-the-master-record",
  :phone=>"1-936-774-6886"
}

{
  :recordid=>"another-generated-detail-record-id",
  :parentid=>"the-same-parent-id-from-the-master-record",
  :email=>"dasia_schuster@wisokytrantow.com"
}
```

And so on.  I'm trying to get this set of records back as an array of hashes.

I've gotten as far as being able to generate the master record, as well as a detail record, but the detail record contains all the keys in the detail.

```
def eventToBreakout(eventhash,sequenceid = -1, parentrecordid = nil, records = [])
    recordid = SecureRandom.uuid
    sequenceid += 1

    recordstruc = {:record_id => recordid, :parent_record_id => parentrecordid, :record_processed_ts => Time.now, :sequence_id => sequenceid}
    eventhash.each_pair do |k,v|
        if recurse?(v)

          eventToBreakout(v,sequenceid,recordid,records)

        else
          if !recordstruc.keys.include?(k)
            recordstruc[k]=v
          end
        end

    end
    records << recordstruc
    records
end
```

I've included my code and here is the output I'm currently getting from it.

```
[{:record_id=>"ed98be89-4c1f-496e-beb4-ede5f38dd549",
  :parent_record_id=>"fa77299b-95b0-429d-ad8a-f5d365f2f357",
  :record_processed_ts=>2016-04-25 16:46:10 -0500,
  :sequence_id=>1,
  :phone=>"1-756-608-8114",
  :email=>"hipolito_wilderman@morar.co",
  :pageUrl=>"http://haag.net/alexie.marvin"},
 {:record_id=>"fa77299b-95b0-429d-ad8a-f5d365f2f357",
  :parent_record_id=>nil,
  :record_processed_ts=>2016-04-25 16:46:10 -0500,
  :sequence_id=>0,
  :eventts=>2016-04-25 22:10:32 -0500,
  :web_id=>"a61c57ae-3a01-4994-8803-8d8292df3338",
  :apikey=>"9adbc7a4-03ff-4fcc-ac81-ae8d0ee01ef0"}]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[mcve]". Your question is good but your code isn't runnable so it won't demonstrate the problem. I'd recommend adding a sample method call to the code to demonstrate the problem. That way everyone trying to help you will be working from the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something along these lines?

```
input = { id: 'parent', value: 'parent value', child: { child_value: 1}}

record = {}
input.each do |k,v|
  if v.is_a? Hash
    v[:parent_id] = input[:id]
    (record[:children] ||= []) << v
  else
    record[k] = v
  end
end

puts record
# {:id=>"parent", :value=>"parent value", :children=>[{:child_value=>1, :parent_id=>"parent"}]}
```

By the way this is a good example to get started with "`spec`" or "`test`" frameworks like `minitest` or `rspec` (both can be used for both). You have defined input and expected output already and "just" need to code until all test/spec-runs are green.